# Variable passed from PHP to Smarty and to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables, smarty

I have an object in php, which is passed to Smarty like $smarty->assign('o',$o)
Then I need to access that object and it's properties in javascript.

How do you do it, without having any javascript in tpl. i want them all in an external file.

If not possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it is not possible. Smarty's `assign` method just passes data from php to templates.

You could create your own smarty function that would output necessary js and use it as modifier in your templates:

```
{$o|jsify}
```

Answer (score 2):

To combine zerkms's and Didozavar's answers, here's a reusable modifier function:

```
<?php

function jsify($object, $name = 'foo'){
    $json_object = json_encode($object);
    return "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> var $name = $json_object; </script>";
}

$smarty->register_modifier("jsify", "jsify");

$smarty->assign("foo", $foo);
$smarty->assign("bar", $bar);

?>

{* In Template *}
{$foo|jsify}
{$bar|jsify:bar}

{* Verify *}
<script type="text/javascript">
    // assuming you're using a browser that supports console
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(bar);
</script>
```

Edit:
After thinking about this, it might be more consistent to make it mirror the template function `{assign}` with a custom function.

```
<?php

function assign_to_javascript($params, $template){
    // validate params values
    $name = $params['var'];
    $json_object = json_encode($params['value']);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> var $name = $json_object; </script>";
}

$smarty->register_function("assign_to_javascript", "assign_to_javascript");

$smarty->assign("foo", $foo);
$smarty->assign("bar", $bar);

?>

{* In Template *}
{assign_to_javascript var="foo" value=$foo}
{assign_to_javascript var="bar" value=$bar}

{* Verify *}
<script type="text/javascript">
    // assuming you're using a browser that supports console
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(bar);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
var variable = {variable}; 
</script>`

Comment: This quite does the trick, as you assign the variable via smarty this way. +1.

Comment: This will only work for very simple variables, not for objects or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following technique and it works for me
use double quote arround smarty variable(single quote is not worked in my case)

```
var base_dir = "{$base_dir}";
```

Comment: This will probably fail when `$base_dir` contains quotes. `var base_dir = '{$base_dir|escape:'javascript'}';` might be better for strings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the solution such that ..content won't appear in the .tpl and hence html

pass the php variable to javascript variable directly in the .php , it will work, and not ...content will appear in the .tpl and html

Comment: Can you please brief your solution if you have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used following technique and it worked for me pretty well.

In test.php file.

```
 $t = new template();
 $t->assign("testVar", $testVar);
 $t->fetch("test.tpl");
```

In test.tpl file. create a div with grabMe.

```
    <div id="grabMe">{$testVar}</div>

    {literal}
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              var testVar = $("#grabMe").text();
        </script>    
    {/literal}
```

It works fine.