# Smarty inside javascript innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

The following code displays `{$products[i]}` tag inside the select menu.I tried `{literal}` but not succeeded.Please tell me how to make this function?.Where I should put {literal} or {rdelim} tags?.

My javascript codes are in an external file and I call this function to add new table data.

```
item_td.innerHTML="<select>{section name=i loop=$products} <option value='{$products[i]}' >&nbsp;{$products[i]}&nbsp;</option> {/section} </select>";
```

Regards.

Comment: If you're expecting Smarty to parse your external JS files which you add to your page via `<script src="...` it isn't gonna happen without some sort of PHP system to read the JS and pass it to Smarty...

Comment: To add to one of Noxt's comments, you can create a global variable in your smarty template which can be used by your external file. See this question on some techniques how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340470/variable-passed-from-php-to-smarty-and-to-javascript

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
item_td.innerHTML="<select>{/literal}{foreach from=$products item=product} <option value='{$product}'>&nbsp;{$product}&nbsp;</option>{/foreach}{literal} </select>";
```

you may need to add / delete `{literal}`

Comment: @Noxt Thanx for the nice try ,


I tried that but not worked.I do almost everything with {literal} tags.Nothing worked for me.

Comment: if you put {literal} at the beginning of JS code, and in the end it does not work?

Comment: @Noxt, as far as I can understand, his code is in an external JS file. No amount of smarty tags will make this work without an infrastructure change.

Comment: @JAAulde, you're right, I did not notice that JS is in an external file.

Comment: @Ceulo, as a way out of this problem - to create a global variable and write it innerHTML text, and then an external file, use this glogal variable

Comment: @Noxt, and just so you know, it was not me who gave your answer a -1