# how to send smarty array in to javascript

Tags: php, smarty

I have smarty array in my `calendar.tpl` file.i'm trying to send that array in to javascript.but i dont know how to do it.

**php file**

```
public function hookDisplayCarrierExtraContent()
    {
$DeliveryWeek=new DeliveryWeek();
$resul=$DeliveryWeek->getweekday();
$this->smarty->assign(array('WeekVal' => $resul));
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/calendar.tpl');
}
```

calendar.tpl

```
<div class="block_content">
{$WeekVal}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var arry= // get smarty array
</script>
```

**------Update---------**

**Solution for me**
you can get array as text
in .tpl

```
<div id="grabMe">{$WeekVal}</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    var arry= $("#grabMe").text();
{/literal}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
var arr = {$WeekVal|json_encode};
```

Comment: i have tried it.then my console showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

Comment: How about this ? `var arr = {$WeekVal|@json_encode};`

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340470/variable-passed-from-php-to-smarty-and-to-javascript

Comment: Thank you very much ` <div id="grabMe">{$testVar}</div>

    {literal}
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              var testVar = $("#grabMe").text();
        </script>    
    {/literal}` worked for me

Comment: You're welcome! Add the working code to your question. Or add an answer.